# INline React.JS styling vs. CSS styling

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a podcast website for someone. It will be the first project I've developed for someone other than myself. I want to deliver the best quality web application with the best coding ethics..
Is it good or bad practice to style inline React.JS??

Comment: Opinion based questions, but I personally recommend to use CSS styling or CSS-in-JS libraries like [styled components](https://styled-components.com/) or [emotion.js](https://emotion.sh/docs/introduction)

Comment: Thanks.. Emotion.JS looks awesome. I'm installing it into my node modules now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS styling. You have all the styles in order there so that when a problem comes up you know exactly where to look.